# How does this program in C sum all the digits in the string?

Tags: c, string

I went to this website: https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sum-all-digits-string/

and they have a funciton that adds up all the digits in a string array. I'm wondering how it's doing this.

```
/*
 * C program to find the sum of all digits present in the string
 */
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char string[80];
    int count, nc = 0, sum = 0;
 
    printf("Enter the string containing both digits and alphabet \n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    for (count = 0; string[count] != '\0'; count++)
    {
        if ((string[count] >= '0') && (string[count] <= '9'))
        {
            nc += 1;
            sum += (string[count] - '0');
        }
    }
    printf("NO. of Digits in the string = %d\n", nc);
    printf("Sum of all digits = %d\n", sum);
}
```

This is the program^
So, correct me if I am wrong, but the for loop is going through each element in the string array until the null character appears, using   count   to represent the element number, right?
And the if statement is doing this: if the element is a number between 0 and 9...
But, I genuinely don't understand what this line does:   sum += (string[count] - '0');

so that line is basically:
sum = sum + (string[count] - '0');
but what does this part do:  (string[count] - '0');
Why do you subtract    0      from the digit in the string array?
Or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: The character `'0'` does *not* have the value 0.  The character `'0'` is just another character, like `'A'` or `'%'`.  In ASCII, `'A'` has the value 65, `'%'` has the value 37, and `'0'` has the value 48.  But in this code, you want to sum the *digit* values, not the character-code values of the characters representing the digits.

Comment: If you summed the character codes, the sum of the digits in `"123"` would be 49 + 50 + 51 = 150, which would be totally wrong.

Comment: `'0'`- `'0'` = `48- 48` = 0, `'1'`- `'0'` = `49 - 48` = 1 etc. 48 being the ASCII code for the character 0, 49 being the ASCII code of the character 1 etc.. `'x'` is shorthand for "ASCII code of x", so you don't need know the ASCII codes of all characters by heart.

Comment: ** string[count] - '0' ** is to get the decimal value of character between 0-9.
let's say string has "015". characters are internally stored as ASCII values only. So the code for string "015" turns out to be

**for '0'** -> 48 - 48, **for '1'** -> 49 - 48 and **for '5'** -> 53 - 48

Comment: `string[count]` is the character code of the digit, which is a number between `48` and `57` in ASCII. The expression `'0'` is the character code of the digit `0`, which is `48` in ASCII. Therefore, the expression `string[count] - '0'` will give you the actual value of the digit, which is a number between `0` and `9`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sum += (string[count] - '0');
```

This is a trick to convert a single *character* digit like `'5'` into the integer 5.

`'0'` is the *character* for 0. All characters are numbers interpreted as characters; you can just use them as numbers. If we look at an [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) we see that `'0'` is the number 48. `'1'` is 49, `'2'` is 50... up to `'9'` at 57. They're all in order and one can take advantage of this. So `'9' - '0'` is `57 - 48` which is... 9!

Similarly, if you want to know the position of a letter in the alphabet (starting from 0) you can do `letter - 'a'` or `letter - 'A'` depending on if it's lower or upper case. (There are [some character sets where this is not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Code_page_layout) but you are very unlikely to encounter these.)

Comment: Should be noted that ISO C only requires `'0' ... '9'` be contiguous (C23§5.2.1). There is no requirement that *letters* be contiguous, although it does hold true for ASCII.

Comment: @Oka [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)... The horror!

Comment: @Oka It's a heretical position, I suppose, but I disagree that this "should be noted".  The probability that someone learning C today will ever encounter a character set incompatible with ASCII is just about exactly: 0.  So trotting out this factoid (true though it is) is a meaningless curiosity at best and a significantly off-putting distraction at worst.

Comment: @SteveSummit This is generally fair, but it doesn't have to be burdened by details. A terse leading explanation of *"With ASCII, letters are in sequence as well, so..."* clarifies the context while remaining technically correct. Food for thought: If I had deleted my comment initially, when the answer was amended, would you have criticized the answer for being accurate?

Comment: @SteveSummit It wouldn't be [C] if someone wasn't being [technically correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo) in the comments. ;) With C's long, long history, this sort historical info is interesting... as long as it's not accompanied with a downvote.